# How can I determine if a string is a Hebrew or Gregorian date?

Tags: c#, date, globalization, hebrew, gregorian-calendar

I have a string value that contains or a Hebrew date, or a Gregorian date. How can I determine if it's Gregorian or Hebrew in C#?

Comment: Can you post samples for the date strings?

Comment: In what formats? If it's just recent dates, can't you just test whether the year is bigger than, say, 3000?

Comment: @svick - That wouldn't work, since the year would look like תשס"ח and not in the form of a number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) method of the `DateTime` object - if it failed with the Hebrew culture you can then try with the Gregorian calendar:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");
culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HebrewCalendar(); // To be sure
DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;

if (DateTime.TryParse("כ\"ה/אייר/תש\"ע", culture, styles, out myDate))
{
   // Hebrew date
}

culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

if (DateTime.TryParse("2/30/2010", culture, styles, out myDate))
{
   // US date
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  DateTime.Now is not a method.  Nor does the he-IL culture use the HebrewCalendar.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Thanks for pointing out my error with `DateTime.Now`. This has been corrected (and I added the `HebrewCalendar`). The code as is stands now works.